# Exchanges whose websites use EV SSL certs?

Tags: exchanges, data-security

What are all the Bitcoin exchanges whose websites have an [Extended Validation (EV) SSL cert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)?

EV certs appear green in Firefox. This is what [Circle](https://www.circle.com/)'s looks like:
[image: Circle.com EV header.png]

The only exchanges that have EV certs that I know of are:

- [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/)
- [Circle](https://www.circle.com/)

[BlockChain.info](https://blockchain.info/) also has one.

Are there others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know one personally in Israel, https://bit2c.co.il it's Israeli bitcoin exchange.